# Logic Pro ES2 High notes lost

Tags: logic-pro

everyone.

I'm a Beginner Dubstep producer. I'm using Logic Pro to make sounds and so on.

So, I Have a big problem, the ES2 cutoff 1+2 lost the high notes as far as it's played, it sounds like compressor.

If someone could help me, please answer this question.

Sorry for my poor english :D

.

Comment: It certainly would be more likely if you provided some more detailed information.

Comment: I solved the problem. It had a limiter.